# Head Code for Custom Taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, wp-head

There is one custom taxonomy (STORE) and i want to add this code to one taxonomy only

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="fr" href="http://www.domain.com/fr" />
```

What code shall i use?

Answer (score 0):

In this case you just need a conditional tag inside of the `wp_head` action. Placing the following on your `functions.php` will solve the problem:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'q166556_taxonomy_head' );

function q166556_taxonomy_head(){
    // Conditional for Taxonomy archives and posts that have any term from the taxonomy `store`
    if ( ! has_term( '', 'store' ) && ! is_tax( 'store' ) ){
        return;
    }

    echo '<link rel="alternate" hreflang="fr" href="http://www.domain.com/fr" />';

}
```